# const correctness of a member function returning a shared_ptr<>

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, constants

if I have the class

```
class foo {
   private:
      std::shared_ptr<char> m_data;
   public:
      std::shared_ptr<const char> GetData()
      { return m_data;}
}
```

I believe that `std::shared_ptr< T >` should cast to `std::shared_ptr< const T >` and share the same object, but what's the const correctness on the function?

`IE` is this valid?

```
std::shared_ptr<const char> GetData() const;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Does the function modify the internal state of the object? No. *
- Does the function give its caller (or other outside environment) modification access to the internal state of the object? No.

This means it's safe to mark it as `const`.

<sup>* Note: @Yakk correctly pointed out in the comments that for some definition of "internal state," the function does indeed modify it, because it increments the reference counter on the `char` owned by the shared pointer `m_data`. You have to decide for yourself whether that constitutes a non-const operation; strictly by the rules of the language, it does not (because it modifies something *pointed to* by the `shared_ptr`, not the `shared_ptr` itself). But since you store a `shared_ptr` in the first place, I assume you're fine with sharing ownership, so doing it shouldn't be viewed as a modification.</sup>

Comment: One caveat is that there is no automatic conversion between ``shared_ptr<char>`` and ``shared_ptr<const char>``. Depending on what you want to do with the result of ``GetData()``, that can be annoying. If the result doesn't need to out-live ``foo`` objects, it may be better to just return a ``const char*`` to ``m_data.get()``.

Comment: @ChristianAichinger On the contrary; there *is* implicit conversion from `std::shared_ptr<char>` to `std::shared_ptr<const char>`: see [constructor (9)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr).

Comment: I wasn't sure about the automatic conversion either so I wrote a test program and it compiled fine. Attempting to change the result failed to compile as expected.

Comment: I ran into a problem like this some time back, sorry if I failed to remember it exactly. My problem back then was with polymorphism. ``shared_ptr``'s of base- and derived classes, and automatic conversion between them. My fault.

Comment: The function does modify the internal state of the object: it increases the reference count of the `std::shared_ptr` the object owns by 1.  It is *still* safe to mark it `const`, but ...

Comment: @Yakk You got me. That's an excellent point, and it hasn't really crossed my mind. I was thinking along the lines of "direct internal state," i.e. modifies data members. Which it does not. But I will expand the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should be very careful with code like that. In the state your code is in at the moment, everything will be safe, because you're only wrapping a `shared_ptr` and nobody can modify the contents because they are private. However, if you extend your code there is a subtle but severe pitfall that can be hard to debug: If you add functions that modify the data to which the `shared_ptr` points, then code that already owns a `shared_ptr` to a `const char` from your `GetData()` function will see the modified data and not a copy of the data.

In C++ the keyword `const` really means **read-only** and not immutable as many think when they first learn it. A way to make your code future-proof would be to use `std::shared_ptr<char>` as data type for your data member `m_data`. If that is not appropriate for your requirements of your code, consider to just return a complete copy of your data when the function `GetData()` is called. Implementing copy-on-write may be necessary, if you have bad performance constraints, but unless you're sure of these performance penalties avoid copy-on-write, because it's tricky because of the reasons above.